# How to return binary data from lambda function in AWS in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, image, aws-lambda, binary

I cannot get python lambda to return binary data. The [node-template for thumbnail images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) works fine but I cannot get a python lambda to work. Below is the relevant lines from my lambda. The `print("image_data " + image_64_encode)` line prints a base64 encoded image to the logs.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    img_base64 = event.get('base64Image')
    if img_base64 is None:
        return respond(True, "No base64Image key")

    img = base64.decodestring(img_base64)
    name = uuid.uuid4()
    path = '/tmp/{}.png'.format(name)

    print("path " + path)

    image_result = open(path, 'wb')
    image_result.write(img)
    image_result.close()

    process_image(path)

    image_processed_path = '/tmp/{}-processed.png'.format(name)
    print("image_processed_path " + image_processed_path)
    image_processed = open(image_processed_path, 'rb')
    image_processed_data = image_processed.read()
    image_processed.close()
    image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_processed_data)

    print("image_data " + image_64_encode)


    return respond(False, image_64_encode)


def respond(err, res):
    return {
        'statusCode': '400' if err else '200',
        'body': res,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png',
        },
        'isBase64Encoded': 'true'
    }
```

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is lambda?

Comment: Do you have any solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Rahul - this is talking about an AWS Lambda function written in Python, not a Python Lambda function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Following all the steps above didn't work on my case, because having the binary support for content-type = `*/*` will convert all responses to binary.

My case:

- Multiple lambda functions returning json (text), just a single lambda returning a binary file. All have **lambda proxy** enabled.
- The lambdas are in an API Gateway
- The API Gateway is behind CloudFront

**Hint:**
I have notice an important information in the API Gateway -> Settings

> [image: Binary support description]

Quoting:

> API Gateway will look at the **Content-Type** and **Accept** HTTP headers to decide how to handle the body.

This means that the **Content-Type** response header must match **Accept** request header

**Solution:**

1. Set Binary Media Types in API gateway to your mime type: image/jpg
2. In your HTTP request set `Accept: image/jpg`
3. In your HTTP response set `Content-Type: image/jpg`

> ```
> {
>   "isBase64Encoded": True,
>   "statusCode": 200,
>   "headers": { "content-type": "image/jpg"},
>   "body":  base64.b64encode(content_bytes).decode("utf-8")
> }
> ```

4. Next we must tell CloudFront to accept the 'Accept' header from the request. So, in CloudFront distribution, click on your API Gateway instance (ID is clickable) and once redirected to CloudFront instance go to **Behaviour** tab, select the path-pattern of your API (example: /api/*) and click on **Edit** button.

> [image: Example of path patterns]

On the new screen, you have to add **Accept** header to Whitelist.

> [image: whitelist Accept]

Note 1: If you have multiple file types, you must add them all to **Binary Media Types** in the API gateway settings

Note 2: For those coming from **serverless** and want to set the binary types when deploying your lambdas, then check this post: [setting binary media types for API gateway](https://medium.com/nextfaze/binary-responses-with-serverless-framework-and-api-gateway-5fde91376b76)

```
plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
- 'image/jpeg'
```

The serverless.yml file for cloudfront should contain:

```
resources:
    WebAppCloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          ...
          CacheBehaviors:
            ...
            - 
              #API calls
              ...
              ForwardedValues:
                ...
                Headers:
                  - Authorization
                  - Accept
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  For me, the part I was forgetting was to include the `Accept` header in the request.  Make sure to check that!

Answer (score 24):

I finally figured this out. Returning binary data from a python lambda is doable.

Follow the instructions here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/

Be sure to *check* the 'Use Lambda Proxy integration' when creating a new method.

Also be sure your Python Lambda response returns a base64-encoded body, sets `isBase64Encoded` to `True`, and an appropriate content type:

```py
import base64

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # ...

    body = base64.b64encode(bin_data)

    return {'isBase64Encoded'   : True,
            'statusCode'        : 200,
            'headers'           : { 'Content-Type': content_type },
            'body'              : body }
```

THEN:

For each of your routes/methods issue:

```
apigateway update-integration-response --rest-api-id <api-id> --resource-id <res-id> --http-method POST --status-code 200 --patch-operations "[{\"op\" : \"replace\", \"path\" : \"/contentHandling\", \"value\" : \"CONVERT_TO_BINARY\"}]"
```

In the AWS console.
The  and  can be seen in the API Gateway 'breadcrumbs'
ex:

```
<api-id> = zdb7jsoey8
<res-id> = zy2b5g
```

THEN:
You need to 'Deploy API'. From what I found only it only worked AFTER deploying the API.

Be sure you setup the 'Binary Media Types' before deploying.

Hint:
Nice AWS shell terminal here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-shell

```
pip install aws-shell
```

Comment: Good tips, but didn't quite get it going for me.  Can you show me exactly how you're encoding `base64_encoded_binary_data`?

Comment: `import base64` `base64_encoded_binary_data=base64.b64encode(bin_data)`

Comment: Thank you @user1495323!  That's very clear.  I think what I was missing was that the "Binary Media Types" are actually matched with the client's incoming `Accept` header, *not* your outgoing `Content-Type` header, so I needed to add `*/*` to my list of Binary Media Types.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

Comment: So, basically, the Lambda function will always receive/send base64-encoded data inside a JSON. Only API Gateway will receive/send binary data with the client?

Comment: Is there anyway to update the integration response via cloudformation template?

Answer (score 10):

As far as I can tell, this is also the case with Python 3.  I'm trying to return a binary data (bytes).  It's not working at all.

I also tried to use base-64 encoding and I have had no success.

This is with API Gateway and Proxy Integration.

[update]

I finally realized how to do this.  I [enabled binary support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html) for type `*/*` and then returned this:

```
return({
        "isBase64Encoded": True,
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
                "content-type": "image/jpg",
        },  
        'body':  base64.b64encode(open('image.jpg', 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8')
})
```

Comment: This is giving me back a 0 by 0 image, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'd first check the contents of image.jpg and ensure that it's available to the Lambda call.  (I didn't do any error checking in the example.)  Try wget/curl to capture the result of the Lambda call through API Gateway.

Comment: Thank you, this is working for me! Do you have an idea why you have to encode it base64 first and then decode it utf-8? In my mind, that's reading it as bytes first, then encoding it base64, then decoding the bytes, then decoding the base64. I would have thought you would have to switch the last 2 operations in order to not mingle the encodings?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem about 6 months ago. Looks like although there is now binary support (and examples in JS) in API Gateway, Python 2.7 Lambda still does not support valid binary response, not sure about Python 3.6.

Base64 encoded response is having problems because of JSON wrapping. I wrote a custom JS on client side taking the base-64 image out of this JSON manually, but this was also a poor solution.

Upload the result to S3 (behind the CloudFront) and return 301 to CloudFront seems to be a good workaround. Works best for me.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was different - you need to redeploy Lambda **after** you do changes Binary Media Types.
That wasn't obvious and I was changing Binary Media Types without any effect and stuck with the issue for days.
For reference .NET core response:

```
var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
{
    StatusCode = 200,
    Body = base64String,
    IsBase64Encoded = true,
    Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"Content-Type", "application/pdf"} 
    }
};
```