# AWS Chalice - Send a File as Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, chalice

I currently have an API setup in the following way.

```
@app.route('/', cors=cors_config, methods=['GET'])
def index():
    request = app.current_request

    file_name = "orders.csv"
    file_path = '/tmp/{}_{}'.format("Life", file_name)

    with open(file_path, 'w') as csvFile:
        field_names = ["OrderID", "OrderedBy", "Agent"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=field_names)
        writer.writeheader()
        for item in range(10):
            writer.writerow(
                rowdict={
                    "OrderID": str(1), 
                    "OrderedBy": "noob",
                    "Agent": "pro"
                }
            )
        csvFile.close()

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        contents = f.read()
    f.close()

    file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename={}'.format(file_name),
        'Content-Length': str(os.path.getsize(file_path))
    }
    return Response(body=contents, headers=headers)
```

Now, when running this code using  I can download the file which is being created here without issues. However after deploying this to my AWS Account, the API endpoint allows me to download a file but it contains the binary string of the file that I want. I read some other posts which indicated to update the contentHandling path to CONVERT_TO_BINARY ([See the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49164783/7183805)) which I did and then redeployed the API from inside API Gateway (not via chalice deploy). It still is showing the same behavior.

Is there any way to solve this?